# android event when url can't be opened because no internet connection

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-webview

I am properly checking if device has internet connection or not but for any other reasons is not suitable for me. 
I need to capture event when a webview tries to open a webpage but this one could not be opened due to internet conection. Now, webview displays standard browser page "www.mypage.com could not be opened...". Which event can be handled for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally check what response the req sent to internet connection gives and if it fails I throw a customised `Exception`.And in my `catch` block I handle it the way I want like give customised message, `alert` or `Toast`.

The conditions I check for which url can't be opened:

1. Server is not reachable(Eg: response code other than 200)
2. No internet connection
3. Connection Timed out
4. Malformed URL
5. Unsupported Encoding or content type
6. Any other exception

Each of them I handle differently using my own exception classes.

Comment: Thanks, onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a WebViewClient that is attached to your WebView to intercept events.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting connection timeout response of sort. Normally, webview would display default result but you can create your own handler to manage it.